# Mac login screen is not the default login screen anymore

Tags: mac, login, login-screen

My Mac's login screen is different from the normal one now and I am not sure why. My current login screen looks a little like this

[image: this]

as opposed to this

[image: this].

Any ideas as to why this has changed? I don't know what settings I have changed recently to make it this way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with **enough detail to identify an adequate answer.**

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I don't think so, because I have always required a password immediately and have never seen this login screen before.

Comment: Could you add the version of macOS you are running and the Mac model, please. You might also find a better answer at "Ask Different" - http://apple.stackexchange.com/